# MySQL Double Equal Sign

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm debugging an old website, and I get some SQL errors.
When I went through it, I found the following query.

```
UPDATE boats
set    new_high_date == DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
WHERE  id=49701
```

I don't know what the **==** here means. Is this a valid query?
I cannot seem to execute it.

I'm not sure if I should change this, or does it mean something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no double equal in MySQL so you should remove it.

Comment: You need to include the proper implementation in your response, not just to remove it, but what should be done instead.

Answer (score 9):

That is incorrect, there is no double equal sign in sql. The correct way to set is

```
UPDATE boats 
SET    new_high_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
WHERE  id = 49701
```

Answer (score 4):

Blindly you can remove them because MYSQL doesn't have any `==`