# How to get selected values in table based on multiple dropdown selection in php

Tags: php

Sql database filtering.  Filter from multiple dropdown lists. One box has character values in database.  Another has numeric values.  I need to extract sgpa values of particular sgpa for a particular class.
If i select class alone is working well with all sgpas.  But specific sgpa's if i select is not working.

```
$select = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from marks where class='$class' and sgpa =='$sgpa'")or die(mysql_error());


$select = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from marks where 
                class='$class' and sgpa =='$sgpa'")or die(mysql_error());
```

particular class with particular sgpa

Answer (score 0):

Firstly mysql does not have double equals [MySQL Double Equal Sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908502/mysql-double-equal-sign) second  you should use prepared statements as this is very insecure.

If you are storing multiple values in spga variable you will need to break them out and use the mysql `WHERE IN (value 1, value2 ....etc)` or create a series of `OR` clauses (`spga = value 1 OR spga = value2`) etc.

Comment: I think i am not clear in posting.  Pl. help me.  I describe my question here.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.  But Pl. give me an simple example for filtering the database based on multiple dropdown boxes.  One should be char value like class such as eight, ninth, etc.,  Another should be marks such as >80 or >90 or >50 etc.,  if i choose both corresponding data must come from the database.