# sqlite3 - efficient way to count rows returned from SELECT statement in PHP without using COUNT()

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm an SQL noob and learning how to use PDO. I'm doing a course which introduces basic user login functions. In an example of a login page, they check the username/password against a MySQL database. I edited their code slightly to be able to simultaneously check whether the user/pass combo exists and also grab the user's first name:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE username='%s' AND password='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));

        // execute query
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $_SESSION["authenticated"] = true;

        // get contents of "firstname" field from row 0 (our only row) 
        $firstname = mysql_result($result,0,"firstname");
        if ($firstname != '')
            $_SESSION["user"] = $firstname;
    }
```

What I want to do is use SQLite instead and do the same thing. Searching around has only resulted in people saying you should use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement, but I don't want to have to use an extra query if it's possible. Since I'm SELECTing the `firstname` field, I should only get 1 row returned if the user exists and 0 if they don't. I want to be able to use that number to check if the login is correct.

So far I've got this:

```
$dsn = 'sqlite:../database/cs75.db';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn);

$sql = sprintf("SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE username='%s' AND password='%s'",
                    $_POST["username"],
                    $_POST["password"]);

// query the database and save the result in $result
$result = $dbh->query($sql);

// count number of rows
$rows = sqlite_num_rows($result);

if ($rows == 1) { ...
```

But this is returning **Warning: sqlite_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given**.

Is there a way I can do this efficiently like in MySQL, or do I have to use a second query?

---

**EDIT**:

I found this, not sure if it's the best way but it seems to work: [How to get the number of rows grouped by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo)

This code let me do it without the second query:

```
// query the database and save the result in $result
$result = $dbh->query($sql);

// count number of rows
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo 'Found: ' . $rows[0];
```

`$rows` is an array so I can just count that to check if it's > 0.

Thanks to everyone who commented. I didn't know until now that there were 2 different approaches (procedural & object oriented) so that helped a lot.

Comment: sorry, that's the database handler. will edit now

Comment: You can't mix db libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can use `PDOStatement::rowCount()`, however, SQLite v3 does not appear to provide rowcounts for queries.

You would need to seperately query the count(*), or create your own counting-query-function.

The documentation comments have [an example of this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#87110)

Answer (score -1):

A bit late, but i tried this with SQLite3 successful:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table_xy');
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
echo count($rows);
```