# PHP PDO query troubleshoot

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

why will the following query not work?

```
$q=$conn->prepare("SELECT GUID FROM :table WHERE URL = :url AND Status = 1 LIMIT 0,1");
$q->execute(array(':table'=>'su_prm_'.$url_params['leading_url'],':url'=>$url_params['trailing_url']));
$r=$q->rowCount();
//returns 0, should return 1. Querying from the console (with quotes) returns 1.
```

I thought perhaps there was an issue whereby the variable strings were not being parsed *as* strings, so tried

```
$q->bindParam(1, 'su_prm_'.$url_params['leading_url'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(2, $url_params['trailing_url'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

also tried placing the variables into new, standalone vars (`$str = 'su_prm_'.$url_params['leading_url']`) and running the query that way. No luck. What am I missing?

EDIT: btw, the strings are 'stream' and 'general'. Nothing fancy...

Comment: Because of this `FROM :table` most probably. I've never seen that type of query, maybe something I don't know yet.

Comment: So placeholders just wont work?

Comment: You will need to specify :table using bindParam rather than via the execute method. It's the same with limit/sort by params :(

Comment: If I specify the table, the where clause should be fine though, right?

Comment: Technically `PDO::rowCount()` is approximately equivalent to `mysqli_affected_rows()` in that it's for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE type queries rather than SELECT so may or may not return the correct value (depending on the database engine) when used to determine the number of rows in a SELECT result.

Comment: Try using `$q->bindValue(':Table', 'su_prm_' . $url_params['leading_url'], PDO::PARAM_STR);` instead of `bindParam`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can't bind to the table name (or field names). You must specify it without a bound parameter. If you're accepting the table name through the URL as a query string parameter then be sure to have a whitelist to check against, to sanitize the input.

```
$table = 'su_prm_'.$url_params['leading_url'];
$whitelist = array(
    'su_prm_A',
    'su_prm_B',
    'su_prm_C'
);

if(!in_array($table, $whitelist))
{
    $table = 'su_prm_A'; // default
    // show message to user - bad table name?
}

$q=$conn->prepare("SELECT GUID FROM $table WHERE URL = :url AND Status = 1 LIMIT 0,1");
```

For counting the number of rows, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo).

Comment: Yeah, I should have figured the query couldnt be prepared this way, I just couldn't see it! Thanks for the help. (will accept when allowed)