# Stop next index from increasing upon integrity violation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dao

I've got the following method in my UserDAO class:

```
public function insert(Array $params)
{   
    $sql  = 'INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, register_date) ';
    $sql .= 'VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, FROM_UNIXTIME(:register_date))';

    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(':firstname',     $params['firstname'],    \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':lastname',      $params['lastname'],     \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':email',         $params['email'],        \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':password',      $params['password'],     \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':register_date', $params['registerDate'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);

    return $sth->execute();
}
```

I've got a `UNIQUE` constraint on my email column, so whenever I'm inserting a new record with a duplicate email, it will throw an exception. That works fine, but I noticed that it still increments the next primary key `id` number while nothing was inserted, so it actually gets skipped over.

How can I stop it from increasing in a case like that, so that I still get a consecutive increase of the index number? (Like 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 1, 3, 5, 7, etc).

Comment: If you have find solution accept the answer (with green button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not really an issue having a non-consecutive `id` column in a table, if you are concerned about the limit of the `id`s datatype you have a two realistic options.

Firstly simply `SELECT` check for the email's existence before the `INSERT`.

Or use something similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, register_date)
SELECT :firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, FROM_UNIXTIME(:register_date)
  FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = :email)
```

You can use the returned row count to check whether a row has been `INSERT`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've email in your database before send insert query.

```
//...
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$sth->execute(array($params['email']));
$rows = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if ($rows[0]) {
    return $sth->execute();
}
```

[How to get the number of rows grouped by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo/6260584#6260584)

Comment: Isn't there any other way? Because I think this defeats the purpose of having a unique constraint. :/

Comment: You really don't need the `COUNT(*)` just `1` will suffice.

Comment: @KidDiamond the unique constraint is there to protect your data, it is not really supposed to be used for information. Exceptions should only really be thrown because something exceptional (not expected) has happened.

Comment: @KidDiamond It is to inscrease speed.