# PHP Medoo - num rows

Tags: php, pdo, medoo

Is it possible to get **number of selected rows** using Medoo? I havent found anything about it in the documentation.

Like num_rows() in mysqli or rowCount in pdo.

Comment: A little serach on google and here it goes : https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-8rqVIeZC6zj8wexroGgAg&gws_rd=cr#safe=active&q=medoo+row+count

Comment: Like I said, could not find any answers, thats why i am asking here, dont you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of rows in SELECT query with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on official Github ticket **#195**

https://github.com/catfan/Medoo/issues/195

> If you are using medoo->select you can use count to check the size of
>   the returned array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

Use select count(ID) in your query

```
$query= "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM socialpic WHERE social_id=$eventid";

$database = new medoo();

$data = $database->query($query)->fetchAll();
```

so you will get $data in array... then you can count them with simple function.

```
$rowcount = count($data);
```