# PDO query went ok but no final result provided

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have troubles with retrieving data from a distant database. Access with PDO to database is ok, i debug.print the rowcount, it returns several occurences, but the code seems to stop when comes the fetching

```
        $arr = $reponse->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here is the link to see by yourself : http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/getTournois.php

I did the ame thing with another db, with same code-like feature, and it's giving me the result

http://bacly.fr/todophp/www/php/getTodo.php

here is my code for getTournois.php :

```
<?php
require("config.php");

    $query="Select t1.tournois_id as tournois_id,t1.tournois_title as tournois_title, t1.tournois_date_debut as tournois_date_debut, t1.tournois_date_fin as tournois_date_fin, t1.tournois_date_limite as tournois_date_limite, coalesce(t2.tournois_inscriptions,0) as tournois_inscriptions, t1.tournois_description as tournois_description,  t1.tournois_simple as tournois_simple, t1.tournois_double as tournois_double, t1.tournois_mixte as tournois_mixte ";
    $query.= " From ";
    $query.= " (select t.tournois_id AS tournois_id, t.tournois_title AS tournois_title, t.tournois_date_debut AS tournois_date_debut, t.tournois_date_fin AS tournois_date_fin, t.tournois_date_limite AS tournois_date_limite, t.tournois_description as tournois_description, t.tournois_simple as tournois_simple, t.tournois_double as tournois_double, t.tournois_mixte as tournois_mixte FROM jnew_tournois_tournois t";
    $query.=" order by tournois_date_limite DESC) t1";
    $query.= " left join";
    $query.= " (select count(ti.tournois_inscriptions_id) as tournois_inscriptions,ti.tournois_inscriptions_tid as tournois_id from jnew_tournois_tournois_inscriptions  ti) t2";
    $query.= " ON t1.tournois_id = t2.tournois_id order by t1.tournois_date_limite desc";

    debug.print($query);

    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO($db_config['SGBD'] .':host='. $db_config['HOST'] .';dbname='. $db_config['DB_NAME'], $db_config['USER'], $db_config['PASSWORD'], $db_config['OPTIONS']);
        $reponse = $bdd->prepare($query);
        $reponse->execute();
        debug.print("rowcount");
        debug.print($reponse->rowcount());

        if ($reponse->rowcount() >0){
            debug.print('fetching');
            $arr = $reponse->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
            debug.print($arr);

        }

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // En cas d'erreur, on affiche un message et on arrête tout
        $result.=$query . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        debut.print($result);   
    }
    $bdd=null;

echo $result = json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Comment: 1) Why do you write `select t.tournois_id AS tournois_id, t.tournois_title AS tournois_title, ...` ? The alias is the same as the column name so this isn't necessary.
2) You print `$arr` before initializing it.

Comment: 1) Yes, you're right, but that's an old code i am reusing for a mobile app (m first one), and it's working so i didnt try to improve it.
2) indeed, i fixed it abd put it after,you can see online, it gives Array, and nothing more

Comment: Are you sure your query does return some rows ? What do you get when you execute it directly on the database ?

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: Can you also check if it is returning either an empty array or `FALSE`?

Comment: i checked my query with phpmyadmin it returns some rows as expected

Comment: i think it's an array, as it puts me Array when i debug.print $arr

Comment: in your example link, the one that shows the full query, I see **pas derreur** at the end. What is that about?

Comment: its just french text i  added to debug.print in the try part of the PDO, meaning there is no error

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works as expected. I think the part that is misleading you into thinking that it does not is `$reponse->rowcount()`.

From PHP Docs,

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the **number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases** and should not be relied on for portable applications.

So I think you should switch to a different row counting method to see if that changes the count. Check out these questions

[How to get the number of rows grouped by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo?rq=1)

[Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)

Comment: Well, i think so my code works, but at least i should get some json data on screen. With the other example written with the same code but sql query and dbname (same provider tho), i have it : http://bacly.fr/todophp/www/php/getTodo.php

Comment: if i i follow your answer, if i remove the test on rowcount() and due to the fact i have a result, i should have some stuff in json at the end, but i don't get anything

Comment: Another thing is that it works perfectly on my local.