# PHP Count array index and convert integer to string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I got an array taken from an mysqli query, this array contain a list of tasks. I must to count how many tasks is in the array ( so only the number of row ) and put in a icon badge as a human readable number.

```
     try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=c9", "andreaem_dev", "");

    //echo "Connected to database<br/>"; // check for connection

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM data_tasks WHERE data_tasks . user = 'admin'"; //I'm selecting ID so only one element on the row is count
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    foreach ($result as $row) {

            $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            echo $row[0];
        }

    $db = null; // close the database connection

}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

With this code i get a int(2) response, the array contains 5 element and i don't know where it takes '2', even i must to convert it in a number.

Thanks in advice for help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/count-number-of-rows-in-select-query-with-pdo here it is.

Comment: thanks, so i must to use $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); ?

Comment: and rows[0] .. read it completely..

Comment: i've put in my foreach as: foreach ($result as $row) {
        
            $task_count = count($row); //HERE I COUNT ROWS
            $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            echo $row[0];
  }        but i get 24? 6 column x 4 task row

Comment: nope. i get a value of 24, bu i've got 5 tasks and 8 colums and don't know where this 24 value come from

Comment: Edit your question with present code.

Comment: done, i've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*sigh*`

You need to use `count()` function in mysql. this is how databases intended to work: they count your data for you. You don't need to count by hand. You don't need to select id. You don't need to loop over results. You don't need to convert number to string. You just have to ask database to count and then get the result.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=c9", "andreaem_dev", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM data_tasks WHERE user = 'admin'";
$count = $db->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot! it works! i'm not a php expert and many times make a lovely spaghetti code