# Checking if database returns result in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have specific issue:

```
if (isset($_POST['dateselected'])) {
                $selecteddate = $_POST['dateselected'];
                list($chosendate) = explode(' ', trim($selecteddate));
                $showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE dateandtime= :chosendate AND lastname= :lastname");
                $showdata->bindParam(':chosendate', $chosendate);
                $showdata->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                $showdata->execute();
                foreach ($showdata as $rowas){
                echo '<div class="twenty name">', $rowas["lastname"], $rowas["firstname"], '</div>';
}}
```

Here is my code, how to print out something, if there is no such result as requested in script? Lets say Database does not contain this kind of condition as it given in: `WHERE dateandtime= :chosendate AND lastname= :lastname`How to check returned values, and print out something if there are no correct result coming back?

Comment: I'm using rowCount() after $showdata->execute(); Value it ALLWAYS get is: -1

Comment: Hmm, I thought I'd used that in the past for `selects` but I guess not doc actually says `For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.`. So guess that was a poor comment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041886/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-grouped-by-column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
if (isset($_POST['dateselected'])) {
            $selecteddate = $_POST['dateselected'];
            list($chosendate) = explode(' ', trim($selecteddate));
            $showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE dateandtime= :chosendate AND lastname= :lastname");
            $showdata->bindParam(':chosendate', $chosendate);
            $showdata->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
            $showdata->execute();
            if ($rowas= $showdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                do {
                    //something with data
                    echo '<div class="twenty name">', $rowas["lastname"], $rowas["firstname"], '</div>';
                } while ($rowas= $showdata->fetch());
            } else {
                echo 'no data';
            }
```

Comment: It gives "no data" when there are no results, but there are - it shows nothing.

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'lastname'

Comment: it does not like line: echo '<div class="twenty name">', $rowas["lastname"], $rowas["firstname"], '</div>'; When information is Correct

Comment: You are my Hero :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

chris 85 mentioned rowcount and this is the right way. This avoid the fetch process if nothing exist. fastest method, it s made for. Also, to speed up the preprocess binding, it is better to specify what data type it is (PDO::PARAM_STR).

```
if (isset($_POST['dateselected'])) {
            $selecteddate = $_POST['dateselected'];
            list($chosendate) = explode(' ', trim($selecteddate));
            $showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE dateandtime= :chosendate AND lastname= :lastname");
            $showdata->bindParam(':chosendate', $chosendate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $showdata->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $showdata->execute();
            $count= $showdata->rowCount();
            if ($count !==0){
                $rowas= $showdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
                foreach ($showdata as $rowas){
                     echo '<div class="twenty name">', $rowas["lastname"], $rowas["firstname"], '</div>';
                }}
            }else {
            echo 'no data';
            }
```

Comment: Ir returns error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)